# Javascript code works on pc but not on teacher website once uploaded

Tags: javascript, html

I working on an interactive math page for my students. This little program down-below works fine on my pc but does not work on line when uploaded to teacher web page.
Could you help me finding the reason behind that please.
Thank you

```
<script>
    function Triarea() {
    var base, height, area;
    base = document.getElementById('base').value;
    height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    area = document.getElementById('area').value;
    if (area === 1 / 2 * base * height) {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = area + " <h2>CORRECT</h2>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = area + " <h2> WRONG try again </h2>";
    }
}
</script>

<h2>Base:</h2> <input type="text" size="25" style="font-size:20pt" id="base" value=""></br>
<h2>Height:</h2> <input type="text" size="25" style="font-size:20pt" id="height" value="">
<br/>
 <span id="results"><h2>Enter your answer in the Area box below then click on calculate</h2></span>
</br>
<h1>Area:</h1> <input type="text" size="25" style="font-size:20pt" id="area"> </br>
<input type="button" size="100" style="background-color: red; color:yellow;height:80px;width:140px;font-size:30px; "  value="Calculate" onClick="Triarea()"><br>
```

Comment: Your question is formatted incoreectly. I recommend putting it into a jsbin instead. http://jsbin.com/

Also, as a student, whenever I tried putting HTML into a school server, most of it got stripped down. That may also be the case - the server is stripping and sanitizing the HTML/JS

Comment: Did you use firebug to look at your hosted page, and see if you're getting any javascript errors?

Comment: It works in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fKSp8/

Answer (score 0):

I did not change any logic, just the placement of the script in the head. Probably you placed your script in a wrong location?

Can you try using the following:

From JSFiddle: [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/3M94J/)

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

Triarea = function() {
    var base, height, area;
    base = document.getElementById('base').value;
    height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    area = document.getElementById('area').value;
    if (area === 1 / 2 * base * height) {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = area + " <h2>CORRECT</h2>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = area + " <h2> WRONG try again </h2>";
    }
}
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <h2>Base:</h2> <input type="text" size="25" style="font-size:20pt" id="base" value=""></br>
<h2>Height:</h2> <input type="text" size="25" style="font-size:20pt" id="height" value="">
<br/>
 <span id="results"><h2>Enter your answer in the Area box below then click on calculate</h2></span>
</br>
<h1>Area:</h1> <input type="text" size="25" style="font-size:20pt" id="area"> </br>
<input type="button" size="100" style="background-color: red; color:yellow;height:80px;width:140px;font-size:30px; "  value="Calculate" onClick="Triarea()"><br>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank for taking the time to fix my code. It did work nicely. Thanks again. That was really kind of you.

Comment: sure.. np! If this answers your question, can you mark this as answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `===` strict equality operator but letting javascript do what it wants with its type inference.

Parse your values as floats using `parseFloat` (or `parseInt` if you prefer ints) to let it know what you're dealing with. You're more likely to get the results you're expecting. Note you may also have to change that equality check to include an epsilon check.

```
base = parseFloat(document.getElementById('base').value);
height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('height').value);
area = parseFloat(document.getElementById('area').value);
```

Updated the previously posted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fKSp8/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will take your advice and use it as I get more knowledge in coding. Thanks again